# Ubuntu Mate Desktop not asking for password after suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, ubuntu-mate

I am struggling with this problem for few days.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed with `ubuntu-mate-desktop`. When I suspend the system, on resume it does not ask for password.

Is there any way to set it so for recovering system will pop-up password window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this solution](https://makandracards.com/makandra-orga/166759-ensure-screen-lock-on-suspen) that worked for me.

First, create file `/etc/systemd/system/lock.service` as root:

```
[Unit]
Description="Make extra sure to lock the screen when suspending"

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/loginctl lock-sessions

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Then, in order to to update system configuration, ​type in console:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable lock.service
```

Comment: This does not work for me on ubuntu mate 22.04. Actually I even tried to execute separately `sudo /bin/loginctl lock-sessions` and does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed mate desktop after you installed vanilla Ubuntu then you have to remove GNOME desktop so that the login screen will be the Mate Lock screen.

Then, you can go to your settings System>Preferences>Look and Feel>Screensaver> Then tick "Lock screen when screensaver is active".

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. When screensaver is active, my system is locked (without having removed GNOME desktop). What I am looking for is that suspend action will also lock the system.

Comment: This may help: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-lock-user-upon-sleep-or-suspend/7787

Comment: Again, same issue. The problem is with **suspend**, not with **lock** or **idle**.

Comment: Some searching leads me to believe this is an issue with MATE going back to 2018. I'm seeing no "solution" only more reports of the same problem. There have been some work arounds but I hesitate to share those here as they are untested and outside the ubuntu platform specifically.