Ubuntu 24.04 is resumes with mouse or keyboard without asking my password. My account gets exposed easily
I've two problems with Ubuntu 24.04 resumption after suspend (not hibernation). The problems are as follows.

I prefer my PC not to wake up with mouse or keyboard, just with power button.
After resume, it doesn't require to enter a password and my account is brought up.


Have you set up a screen lock?

I could at last use these guides to overcome the lack:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/power-management-acpi-wake-up-settings/17344
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384924/ubuntu-mate-desktop-not-asking-for-password-after-suspend
It's a question; Why the ubuntu itself should not have a built-in option for this purpose? Being locked should not be an option and should be always true! Even with 24.04 we're experiencing such incorrections.

Your question does not mention Mate. If you are using Ubuntu Mate, then edit your question and add that information.

This question is similar to: How to resume from suspend or hibernate only by the power button?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See this Ubuntu help page for how to enable screen lock.
